# How to return one generated line from csv?

Tags: python, csv

I'd like to yield results from a large array (coming from the database) to the browser (with Flask) using the method shared in [their documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/) :

```
@app.route('/large.csv')
def generate_large_csv():
    def generate():
        for row in iter_all_rows():
            yield ','.join(row) + '\n'
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
```

With a twist : Instead of generating the csv myself (join with ',', adding a breakline), I'd like to use the `csv` package.

Now, the only way I found to return only one written line is to do the following :

```
@app.route('/large.csv')
def generate_large_csv():
    def generate():
        for row in iter_all_rows():
            dest = io.StringIO()
            writer = csv.writer(dest)
            writer.writerow(row)
            yield dest.getvalue()

    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
```

But creating a new `io.StringIO` & `csv.writer` for every row just does not seems right at all!

I took a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) of the package, but I wasn't able to find something that would only return one line.

Comment: is the csv you want to "stream" with static or dynamic contents?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question ; The `row` is a result from the database. It could contains 0 rows up to millions. It's not a file stored in the disk.

Comment: yes I think I misunderstood your question too because you haven't mentioned where the source comes from. So I wonder if the content you want to stream is either static of dynamic. The reason I ask is because if the content is static, you have an option not to stream by using flask but by the web server itself like Nginx

Comment: Yes of course, if it were static I would have done that :)

Comment: I updated the question to be more precise

Comment: I don't have much experience on streaming using Flask, but it seems from the docs and your approach that using in-memory to buffer each csv row + generator is the one correct way to do it. Although if I were you, I may be tempted to do a periodical job to perform a csv-like dump from the DB, just serve by Nginx-like server. In this case you keep your DB less busy (think about multiple concurrent connections etc.), streaming in my opinion is better suited for webserver :)

Comment: It's not possible (I think) because the generated csv is asked by the user, and contains data specific to that user, that are updated regularly, and can be filtered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to it easily with a custom file object. If you create an object with a `write` method that simply stores its input and give it to a csv writer, it is done :

```
class keep_writer:
    def write(self, txt):
        self.txt = txt

@app.route('/large.csv')
def generate_large_csv():
    def generate():
        kw = keep_writer()
        wr = csv.writer(kw)  # add optional configuration for the csv.writer
        for row in iter_all_rows():
            wr.writerow(row)  # just write the row
            yield kw.txt      # and yield the line build by the csv.writer
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
```